# Automatically include header files in intellisense with vscode when using precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am on macOS 10.15, I am using vscode for a project. For this project, I set up precompiled headers. The compilation works well, but the precompiled headers are not included in my files. Instead, they are included with the compiler option `-include pch.hpp` (as stated [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/llvm/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#precompiledheaders) ). The problem is that because I have not those includes in my file, IntelliSense is not working well and I have a lot of include error. In the `c_cpp_properties.json` I tried to add the line

```
"compilerArgs": [
"-include ${workspaceFolder}/emulator/pch.hpp"
]
```

but it didn't work, the errors are still here. Is there a way to tell IntelliSense to automatically include a file ?

What I did before was to have

```cpp
#ifndef BUILD
   #include "pch.hpp"
#endif
```

in a `util.hpp` file included in all my other files and to define BUILD with `-DBUILD` when compiling. The problem is that whenever I modify my `util.hpp` file I have to recreate my precompiled headers file because I had an error from clang telling me that my `util.hpp` file was newer than the precompiled header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **forcedInclude**, c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
       ...
       "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/config.h"],
       ...
    }
]
```